# Duplicate rows, according to value in a column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I want to read an Excel File and want my code to duplicate rows according to the value in one of the columns in that excel file.

e.g.

```
    Col 1  Col 2
0   Adam      3
1  Sarah      2
2   John      0
```

I want my code read above file and copy Adam's row 3 times and Sarah's row 2 times and export in a new file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if detault `RangeIndex`:

```
print (df.index.repeat(df['Col 2']))
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype='int64')

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Col 2'])].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Col 1  Col 2
0   Adam      3
1   Adam      3
2   Adam      3
3  Sarah      2
4  Sarah      2
```

And then:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

General solution for duplicated Index or `DatetimeIndex` is repeat numpy array created by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and selecting by positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[np.arange(len(df)).repeat(df['Col 2'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

EDIT:

Solution without `np.repeat`:

```
df =df.loc[[c for a, b in zip(df.index, df['Col 2']) for c in [a] * b]].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Col 1  Col 2
0   Adam      3
1   Adam      3
2   Adam      3
3  Sarah      2
4  Sarah      2
```

Comment: Thank you Jezrael for your help but i am getting a TypeError - TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: Try `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Col 2']).astype(np.int64)].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

here is the code i am using but still getting Type Error.
readFile = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(readFile)


x = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Col 2']).astype(np.int64)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(x)

Comment: @Mob - It looks like pandas verxion issue, what is your version of pandas?

Comment: Hi Jezrael, Thank you for all your help - pandas: 0.23.0

Comment: @Mob - It is bad, I try google solution and it seems numpy bug https://github.com/bytefish/facerec/issues/57 :(

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate your help. can you suggest a different way of repeating rows?

Comment: @Mob - Hard question, how working `df = df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df), dtype=np.int64), df['Col 2'].values.astype(np.int64))].reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: @Mob - added solution without `np.repeat`

Comment: Thank you jezrael this one works. Thank you very much, i really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

another way to solve this,

```
pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df['Col 1'].repeat(df['Col 2'])),df,on=['Col 1'])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.